# error in event handing in data binding android

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am getting the error:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find method handler on ViewDataBinding app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml loc:55:27 - 55:76 ****\ data binding error ****



<data class="ActivityMainBinding">
        <variable
            name="login"
            type="***.loginViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="***.LoginHandler" />
    </data>

<Button
        android:onClick="@{() -> handler(context).onLoginButtonClicked(login)}"
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Sign In"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/user_password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_password"/>
```

ANd the login handler class:

```
class LoginHandler(mContext: Context) {

    var mContext=mContext as Activity

    fun onLoginButtonClicked(userInfo: loginViewModel){

        Log.i("Email is ",userInfo.userEmailAddress)
        Log.i("Password is ",userInfo.userPassword)

       userInfo.login(userInfo.userEmailAddress, userInfo.userPassword, mContext)

    }

}
```

Why am I getting this error? I am rechecked the function name and syntax on click.

Solution tried: 1. Clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: on click use the fun name only in xml

Comment: you mean only onLoginButtonClicked(login) will work? @Nithinlal

Comment: no onLoginButtonClicked() only work on xml

Comment: @Nithinlal doesn't get you

Answer (score 0):

`handler` is defined as a variable, so `handler(context)` makes no sense.

You will need to just use `handler` and initialize the object in your code.

`handler.onLoginButtonClicked(login)`

Comment: I tried using this         android:onClick="@{() -> LoginHandler(context).onLoginButtonClicked(login)}"
but not worked. Can you explain your answer by sample code? @Kiskae

Comment: Looking through the databinding docs it looks like creating new objects isnt possible. So you will need to initialize `handler` in your code and just call the method with `handler.on*`.

Comment: so I can't pass the context in the handler?

Comment: @Ankur_009 You can `context` (or any other variable) to any method. But you **cannot create new objects** inside databinding expressions. What you are trying to do is like this.
`String name = "My name";
name("another name");`
which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @muthuraj so how would I call the onLoginButtonClicked() from xml?

Comment: @Ankur_009 You need to bind the variable (`handler`) after layout inflation.
For ex, 
`val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);`
 then you need to set `handler` like this.
`binding.handler = Handler(this)`
Then you can access `handler. onLoginButtonClicked()` from xml

Comment: @muthuraj I tried this way also but end up getting the error msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type lambda

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiarized with data binding, but I read you should declare ***import*** on top of your layout.

```
<data>
    <import type="***.LoginHandler"/>
</data>
```

Info: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#layout_details